# i wrote a program to display a table using panda. now i want to save the table in a database. the codes should be continued

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7, database-design

```
***import pandas as pd
employees = {'Name of Machining': ['milling','Drilling','Drilling','Chamfering'],
             'Speed': [275,275,275,275],
             'Feed': [0.28,0.03,0.03,0.28],
             'Tool': ['EndMill','TwistDrill','TwistDrill','EndMill']
            }
df = pd.DataFrame(employees, columns= ['Name of Machining','Speed','Feed','Tool'])***

i have used panda to contruct a table here. I am working on the project to save the table in
```

a database how can i save the table so constructed in a database)

print (df)

Answer (score 0):

If it's a MySQL database, you can use the [**`SQLAlchemy`**](https://www.sqlalchemy.org/) toolkit.
Make sure to run this in your terminal (for Windows) to install the packages :

```
pip install sqlalchemy pymysql
```

And then you can use [**`pandas.DataFrame.to_sql`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) to create, append or overwrite a table :

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

# - Creating the dataframe 
employees = {'Name of Machining': ['milling','Drilling','Drilling','Chamfering'],
             'Speed': [275,275,275,275],
             'Feed': [0.28,0.03,0.03,0.28],
             'Tool': ['EndMill','TwistDrill','TwistDrill','EndMill']
            }
df = pd.DataFrame(employees)

# - Creating an engine to connect to MySQL Database
host, db, user, pw = "localhost", "mydb_name", "my_user_name", "my_password"
engine = create_engine(f"mysql+pymysql://{user}:{pw}@{host}/{db}")

# - Inseting the dataframe to the MySQL table                                   
df.to_sql('employees', engine, index=False)
```

> Read [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/engines.html) in the official documentation to understand more.

Comment: now how can i print/show the data

Comment: What do you mean by _print/show the data_ ? What data exactly and from where to where ?